# How do you sign out of Xbox Games on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

I signed in with the wrong account on Windows 8. How do I sign out of the incorrect account and match up my real Xbox Games account on Windows 8?

Comment: The link below will help you figure it out. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EUEfLeupLPE

Answer (score 2):

Taken from the [official Xbox Live page](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/Live/ChangeUser):

> To switch to a different Microsoft account than the one you’re signed
>   in with in your Xbox app—as you’d want to do if your Xbox gamertag is
>   associated with a different Microsoft account (formerly known as a
>   Windows Live ID)—do the following.
>
> **Sign in to your PC using a different Microsoft account**
>
> On your PC, select the **Settings** charm. Select **More PC
>   settings**. Select **Users**. Under **Other users**, select an
>   account.
>
> If needed, select **Add a user** and enter the email address and
>   password for the Microsoft account you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had to uninstall & reinstall the games app.

** Edit **

Try This.

- Press Windows + I
- Go to "Change PC Settings" at the bottom.
- Go to "Users"
- Select "Disconnect Your Microsoft Account"

Comment: I've uninstalled and reinstalled, however it automatically logs me back in with the incorrect account. :-(

Comment: updated answer.